# Reading a text file into an array in PASCAL

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a text file "text.txt" that contains

```
48 42
```

I am trying to read the text file and assign it into an array. After that I am trying to assign the numbers into num1 and num2 variables.

Below is what I have right now. For some reason, it does not assign the numbers using array index.

```
program tutorial15;
  var
    infile, outfile: text;
    inputchar: char;
    num1: integer;
    num2: integer;
  begin
    assign(infile, 'text.txt');
    reset(infile);
    while not eof(infile) do
      begin
        while not eoln(infile) do
          begin
            read(infile, inputchar);
          end;
          num1 := inputchar[0];
          num2 := inputchar[1];
      end;
    writeln('Number1: ', num1);
    writeln('Number2: ', num2);
  end.
```

I am new to Pascal, please let me know what I could do to solve this problem!

Comment: You're not putting anything into an array, because you don't have an array. You declared `inputchar: char;`, which is a single character. Single characters don't have array indexes. Go back to your course notes and re-read the section about arrays. Your text file would also contain three characters, not two - the space between them is a character as well.

Comment: Actually, reading your post again, your text file contains **5** characters, because each digit is a character, and the space between the two pairs of characters is a character as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
program readtoarray;
var
        f: TextFile;
        i: Integer;
        a: array [0..1] of Integer;
begin
        assign(f, 'text.txt');
        reset(f);
        i := 0;
        while not eof(f) do begin
                read(f, a[i]);
                inc(i);
        end;
        close(f);
        for i := 0 to 1 do writeln('Number', i+1, ': ', a[i])
end.
```